# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: aside - Only Safari Error

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari

So I have this js code:

```
<body>
    // Content here (including the aside element)...

    <script>
        const asideInner = document.querySelector('aside .aside-inner')
        if (asideInner !== null) {
            const aside = document.querySelector('aside')
            function checkSidebarHeight() {
                const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
                const sidebarHeight = asideInner.offsetHeight;

                if (sidebarHeight > windowHeight) {
                    asideInner.style.position = 'relative';
                    aside.style.marginTop = '185px'
                } else {
                    asideInner.style.position = 'sticky';
                    aside.style.marginTop = '202px'
                }
            }
            checkSidebarHeight()
            window.addEventListener('resize', checkSidebarHeight)
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

It seems to work on all browsers just fine except on Safari, there I get: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: aside`

If you need more info tell me cause Im not sure what other info you might need.
Thank you

Comment: try [this code](https://pastebin.com/gTUQzgug) - I have a suspicion, but no safari to test it on

Comment: @JaromandaX Hey it works perfectly, thank you. I asked one more question here which may be similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77010143/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-lozad-only-safari-error I spent my whole day and I cant figure it out. Thank you, you've been really helpful.