# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: lozad - Only Safari Error

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, mobile-safari

So in my website I'm using a library called lozad to load my images (its basically a lazy loader). Here's what I have in my HTML file:

```
<body>
    // Content here (this is how img elements look like)...
    <img class="lozad" data-src="https://unsplash.it/1600/900">

    // Script here...  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/lazyload.js"></script>
    <script>
        const observer = lozad();
        observer.observe();
    </script>
</body>
```

and in the lazyload.js file I have all the code from the library (basically just selected everything and pasted in the lazyload.js). You can find the code here: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lozad/dist/lozad.min.js

With this it works just fine in all browsers except Safari. There I'm getting: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: lozad`

Then I tried to just replace the script src to the cdn like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lozad/dist/lozad.min.js"></script>`

and it somehow works just fine, but I need the code to be in my js file, not load it from the cdn.

Thank you

Comment: A link to the minified file is not useful.

Comment: Is it getting an error trying to load the `lazyload.js` file before you changed the script tag?

Comment: @Pointy Its just simple code (maybe use a code formatter online to format it). Someone who understands js well can maybe figure it out.

Comment: @Barmar well, looks like yes, didnt think of it before but I added a console.log to the lazyload.js file and I see it logs the string in all browsers except Safari, so that might have to do something with the not loading the js file. I went to page/static/lazyload.js and it goes to the js file normally

Comment: I'm not sure why this would differ between browsers. Either the .js URL is correct or it isn't.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, thats how it should be but Safari has these strange things.

Comment: I doubt that Safari parses URLs differently. That would break EVERYTHING.

Comment: @Barmar Not sure, maybe there's someone here who can explain. If you have safari you can check the website yourself: https://tigerteamx.com

Comment: I get a different error: `Can't find variable: aside`

Comment: The code in your `lazyload.js` doesn't look anything like the code in `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lozad/dist/lozad.min.js`. There's no mention of `lozad` in your script.

Comment: @Barmar Oh yeah, totally forgot that the website isnt live with the latest changes. So I had this aside error which someone solved it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77003859/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-aside-only-safari-error?noredirect=1&lq=1 and the LazyLoad was another library I used to load lazy images, but the aside error was before the lazyload so it just throws error of the aside and doesnt continue with the script below. After fixing the aside error, I got the same error as lozad except now Reference error => variable LazyLoad